# Hive-1.1.0 showing an error while inserting data into created table(using hadoop-2.5.1)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

Successfully i created table by using :

```
CREATE  TABLE movie_example 
   (title STRING, id BIGINT, director STRING, 
    year BIGINT, genres ARRAY<STRING>) 
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '$' MAP KEYS 
    TERMINATED BY '#' LINES 
   TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

and when i try to insert data to this table by using :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/<path>/hiveExample.txt' 
   OVERWRITE INTO TABLE movie_example;
```

Its throwing an error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getKeyProvider()Lorg/apache/hadoop/crypto/key/KeyProvider;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims$HdfsEncryptionShim.<init>(Hadoop23Shims.java:1152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims.createHdfsEncryptionShim(Hadoop23Shims.java:1279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getHdfsEncryptionShim(SessionState.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.replaceFiles(Hive.java:2747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.replaceFiles(Table.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadTable(Hive.java:1582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask.execute(MoveTask.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this is a bug when I did a search.

[Hive 1.1.0 not compatible with Hadoop 2.4.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9957)

Comment: any solutions for this bug?

Comment: Upgrade Hadoop to 2.6 should be a solution. Please follow the jira